# Weird screen flickering and baloo crashing on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am facing these two issues

1. Sometimes screen starts to flicker, not everyday but maybe two or three times a week. Logging out and then logging back in stops it from happening.
2. Baloo file indexer crashes everyday, usually after 3-4 hours of laptop usage.

I am using Kubuntu on Hp pavilion g6 notebook with intel i5 processor and intel HD 4000 graphics. I am new to linux and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: **1**: It's preferable to ask about separate issues in separate questions. **2**: You can disable *baloo* via *System Settings > Search*. **3**: See if you can correlate the screen flickering with some application running at the time.

Comment: Will disabling Baloo have any negative effect on system (like getting slow)?

Comment: Disabling baloo will not slow down the system. You will of course lose the search functionality of baloo. There are suggestions about improving baloo's stability. But such a question may not be a good fit for Ask Ubuntu. You'd be better off asking at https://www.kubuntuforums.net or https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/